# SAS Tabulate Issue

Tags: sas

I need to produce a report and used the PROC Tabulate in SAS.The Code I used produce the report with Sub_LOB, Group and Mat_Month and the totals column. With in the Mat_Month there are three sub-columns (Dec 16, Jan17 and Feb17).I wrote the code but ***it produce the columns in order like Dec 16,Feb17 and Jan17)*** which is not I wanted. Also, I need one empty row for the group named "CAROLINA GROUP" but the complete row disappears since there are now data in that row. Is there any way we can produce the sub columns in the same way I wanted. Also, is it possible to get the row though it has no values now but can have the values in the future.The code I used are as:

```
PROC Tabulate 
DATA= T_Final_Summary Format=Comma12. ;
VAR Comm Net_Bal;
Class Mat_Month / ORDER=Unformatted MISSING;
Class Sub_LOB /ORDER=Unformatted MISSING;
Class Group /ORDER= Unformatted MISSING;
TABLE /*Row Dimension*/
Sub_LOB={LABEL= “ “} * 
(Group={LABEL=” “} 
ALL={LABEL=”Grand Total”})
ALL={LABEL=”Grand Total},

/*Column Dimension*/

Mat_Month *(
Comm={LABEL=”Count of Comm} *N={LABEL=” “}
Comm={LABEL=”Sum of Comm} *Sum={LABEL=” “}
Net_Bal={LABEL=”Count of Net Bal”}*N={LABEL=” “}
Net_Bal ={LABEL=”Sum of Net Bal”}*Sum={LABEL=”Sum of Net Bal”})
ALL={LABEL=”Grand Total}*(
Comm={LABEL=”Total Count of Comm} *N={LABEL=” “}
Comm={LABEL=”Total Sum of Comm} *Sum={LABEL=” “}
Net_Bal={LABEL=”Total Count of Net Bal”}*N={LABEL=” “}
Net_Bal ={LABEL=”Total Sum of Net Bal”}*Sum={LABEL=”Sum of Net Bal”})
/*Table Options*/
/BOX=(LABEL=”Sub Lob/Group”} Missing =”0”;
RUN;
```

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide an example input dataset, as text, within your question.

Comment: For the second part of your question I suggest you look into the `classdata` option.

Comment: I'm fairly certain it should be one problem per question, you have two clear issues. Your second is already answered here, for PROC REPORT but the same is applicable to PROC TABULATE. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1498001/how-can-i-get-proc-report-in-sas-to-show-values-in-an-across-variable-that-have/1498191#1498191

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the order of the variable, it's sorting alphabetically. The variable in MAT_MONTH needs to be an actual SAS date to have it sort accordingly, which would mean numeric with a date format (MONYY5). You'll need to do the conversion before the PROC TABULATE step.

Then replace mat_month in your proc tabulate with the mat_month_date variable.

```
data want;
set have;
  mat_month_date=input(have, anydtdte.);
  format want monyy5.;
run;
```